# Visual Studio c++ python lib

Tags: python, c++, visual-studio, linker-errors

I have downloaded python 2.7.

I add libs/include folder to linker/compiler, but get the following linker error:

```
1>dllmain.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _PyString_FromString
```

Comment: Which libs have you added?

Comment: http://www.python.org/ftp/python/2.7.6/python-2.7.6.msi

And folder libs

Comment: You added the msi to the list of libs to link?

Comment: noo i downloaded this MSI install and from folder add dir "libs" to linker

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you defaulted all the paths:
Add the Python library to the project

```
python27.lib
```

Add the Python directories to the project

```
C:\Python27\include
C:\Python27\libs
```

Remember to set the linker output as a .pyd file

Output directory should be `C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages`, or copy the resulting .pyd file to site_packages yourself.

**Make sure this is for All Configurations**

Comment: But this is visual c++ and i want to write program in c++ i have only python inserts like:
  `PyObject* args = PyTuple_New(2);
 PyTuple_SetItem(args, 0, PyInt_FromLong(1L));
 PyTuple_SetItem(args, 1, PyString_FromString(msg));`

Comment: @user2653995: did you add python27.lib to your linker library list in the project?

Comment: C:\Python27\libs;C:\Program Files %28x86%29\Microsoft Research\Detours Express 3.0\src;%(AdditionalLibraryDirectories)

python27.lib is in c:\python27\libs

Comment: @user2652995: everyone makes mistakes, but the idea of this site is to learn from other's.  So, don't be embarrassed, what did you do wrong?  That way, if someone comes to this page from Google they can slap their forehead and say "Dohhh" and fix.

Comment: Make sure you're compiling your project with the same configuration as the included lib (x64 or x86 depending on your python installation)